# Importing MYSQL images in bootstrap carousel

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

As the topic indicate, I have inserted some image i links in a column. And I want to add them to a bootstrap carousel, But the problem is that there are three images, and all the images come below one another. My code will explain all. Hoping to get an answer, that's all I can explain! Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CineMate - AhadAman</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<!--   
       CAROUSEL    -->
       <?php
       include_once('admins/conn.php');
       $select = "SELECT * FROM slide_show";
       $run = mysqli_query($conn,$select);
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {


       ?>
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo $row['img_url']; ?>" alt="First slide">
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- 
       CAROUSEL END -->
       <?php
    }
    ?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For display image from mysql try this

```
<img class="d-block w-100" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['img_url']); ?>" alt="First slide">
```